# Differentiation of integrals with functions as limits

Tags: derivatives, definite-integrals

How do I differentiate an integral with two functions and the limits as functions too such as $\int_{t-\tau}^{t}s(t)i(\theta) d\theta$.
$\tau\leq\theta\leq0$.

Comment: Look at this [Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

Comment: What is the meaning of $i$ and what is the relation between $t$ and $\theta$? From the way you wrote the integral, $s(t)i$ has no apparent $\theta$-dependence, so the integral is $s(t)i\int_{t-\tau}^t\theta\,d\theta$ and you can compute that integral explicitly as a function of $t$.  So probably you made a bad typo.

Comment: If you have a good method to justify differentiation under the integral sign for constant bounds, then to generalize the result to bounds that vary with $t$ you can use the multivariable chain rule. See Corollary 12.4 in https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/diffunderint.pdf.

Comment: Thank you so much for your responses.  I made a typo, also $\tau\leq\theta\leq0$.